# button wont save to database it comes to exception error

Tags: asp.net, database, exception, button, save

i made a asp.net site with 3 textboxes and 1 dropdown list and a save button evvry time i click it, it give back An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Bon-Temps.dll but was not handled in user code.

it give this error on de code line 
 DataRow drow = ds.Tables["OpdrachtGever"].NewRow();

my question is why??

```
 SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
       cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BT-1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from  OpdrachtGever";
    cmd.Connection = cnn;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "OpdrachtGever");
    SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    DataRow drow = ds.Tables["OpdrachtGever"].NewRow();
    drow["Naam"] = TextBox1.Text;
    drow["Adres"] = TextBox2.Text;
    drow["PostCode"] = TextBox3.Text;
    drow["AantalPersonen"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem;


    ds.Tables["OpdrachtGever"].Rows.Add(drow);
    da.Update(ds, "OpdrachtGever");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have named your table as

```
da.Fill(ds, " OpdrachtGever ");
             ^             ^
```

but then you refer to it with

```
DataRow drow = ds.Tables["OpdrachtGever"].NewRow();
```

without any spaces.

There is a rogue space also on this line

```
ds.Tables["OpdrachtGever "].Rows.Add(drow);
                        ^
```

It is not a good idea to have these spaces in your table name because they are not meaningfull for us (humans) and easy to forget. But, for the indexer of the table collection, a space makes a difference. So, when you pass the name with the wrong or missing spaces, the indexer is not able to find your table and returns `null` .

Comment: editted that one out but didnt help the first problem is solved need to put in the name of the connection string it self not the full string.

Comment: Same problem on the da.Fill. Do not put spaces around your table names.

Comment: changed that out to but it still hangs on same line

Comment: now it shuts down at the following line 
 drow["AantalPersonen"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem;

with the error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <3> in AantalPersonen Column.  Expected type is Decimal.

Comment: Well, now this is a different error. The SelectedItem is an object the exact nature depends on how do you fill the combo.